# Python - All combination of list of lists without duplicates

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I would like do a combination of list of lists of string without duplicate of strings inside a combination result but I don't find how to do this.

For example:

```
# Input
pickup_list = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e"], ["a", "c", "f"]]
print(combinaison_function(pickup_list))

# Output
> [["a", "d", "c"], ["a", "d", "f"], ["a", "e", "c"], ["a", "e", "f"], ["b", "d", "a"], ["b", "d", "c"], ...]
```

In the exemple ["a", "d", ”a"] isn't returned because "a" is a duplicate and that I want to do.

I guess the solution will be with an itertools function but I don't find how to do.

Thanx for your replies in advance.

Comment: What is you combination function at this moment?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `itertools.product()` then filtering duplicates. A quick way to check for duplicates is casting to a `set`.

```
comb_list = []
for comb in itertools.product(*pickup_list):
    if len(set(comb))==len(comb):
        comb_list.append(comb)
```

with your `pickup_list` I get:

```
[('a', 'd', 'c'), ('a', 'd', 'f'), ('a', 'e', 'c'), ('a', 'e', 'f'), ('b', 'd', 'a'), ('b', 'd', 'c'), ('b', 'd', 'f'), ('b', 'e', 'a'), ('b', 'e', 'c'), ('b', 'e', 'f'), ('c', 'd', 'a'), ('c', 'd', 'f'), ('c', 'e', 'a'), ('c', 'e', 'f')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own recursive generator:

```
def uCombo(L,used=None):
    if used is None: used = set()   # track used values
    if not L: yield [];return       # end of recursion
    for n in L[0]:                  # combine each unused value
        if n in used: continue      # with remaining sub-lists
        yield from ( [n]+c for c in uCombo(L[1:],used | {n}) )
```

output:

```
pickup_list = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e"], ["a", "c", "f"]]
for combo in uCombo(pickup_list): print(combo)
                     
['a', 'd', 'c']
['a', 'd', 'f']
['a', 'e', 'c']
['a', 'e', 'f']
['b', 'd', 'a']
['b', 'd', 'c']
['b', 'd', 'f']
['b', 'e', 'a']
['b', 'e', 'c']
['b', 'e', 'f']
['c', 'd', 'a']
['c', 'd', 'f']
['c', 'e', 'a']
['c', 'e', 'f']
```